# Python Wordlist.txt generator

Tags: python, python-3.x

Okay, this is wrong I can feel it, But I cant seem to figure out how to properly iterate through my second list.... (It creates the file in the proper way and iterates but i want to make the script more compact as i want to be able to have num = [0-999] somehow. *NOTE* I DO realize how large this file is going to get when done.)

```
filename = "mywordlist.txt"


adj = ["united", "dramatic", "green"]
noun = ["ladder", "axe", "tiger"]
num = ["0", "1", "2"]


File = open(filename, "w")
File.write(adj[0]+noun[0]+num[0])
File.write("\n")
File.write(adj[0]+noun[0]+num[1])
File.write("\n")
File.write(adj[0]+noun[0]+num[2])
File.write("\n")
File.write(adj[0]+noun[1]+num[0])
File.write("\n")
File.write(adj[0]+noun[1]+num[1])
File.write("\n")
File.write(adj[0]+noun[1]+num[2])
File.write("\n")
File.write(adj[0]+noun[2]+num[0])
File.write("\n")
File.write(adj[0]+noun[2]+num[1])
File.write("\n")
File.write(adj[0]+noun[2]+num[2])
File.write("\n")
File.write(adj[1]+noun[0]+num[0])
File.write("\n")
File.write(adj[1]+noun[0]+num[1])
File.write("\n")
File.write(adj[1]+noun[0]+num[2])
File.write("\n")
File.write(adj[1]+noun[1]+num[0])
File.write("\n")
File.write(adj[1]+noun[1]+num[1])
File.write("\n")
File.write(adj[1]+noun[1]+num[2])
File.write("\n")
File.write(adj[1]+noun[2]+num[0])
File.write("\n")
File.write(adj[1]+noun[2]+num[1])
File.write("\n")
File.write(adj[1]+noun[2]+num[2])
File.write("\n")
File.write(adj[2]+noun[0]+num[0])
File.write("\n")
File.write(adj[2]+noun[0]+num[1])
File.write("\n")
File.write(adj[2]+noun[0]+num[2])
File.write("\n")
File.write(adj[2]+noun[1]+num[0])
File.write("\n")
File.write(adj[2]+noun[1]+num[1])
File.write("\n")
File.write(adj[2]+noun[1]+num[2])
File.write("\n")
File.write(adj[2]+noun[2]+num[0])
File.write("\n")
File.write(adj[2]+noun[2]+num[1])
File.write("\n")
File.write(adj[2]+noun[2]+num[2])
File.write("\n")
File.close()
```

I thought about somehow doing...

```
adj = ["united", "dramatic", "green"]
noun = ["ladder", "axe", "tiger"]
num =["0", "1", "2"]

 
for x in range(len(adj)): 
    print(adj[x]+noun[0])
    print(adj[x]+noun[1])
    print(adj[x]+noun[2])
    
    print(adj[x]+noun[0]+num[0])
    print(adj[x]+noun[0]+num[1])
    print(adj[x]+noun[0]+num[2])

    print(adj[x]+noun[1]+num[0])
    print(adj[x]+noun[1]+num[1])
    print(adj[x]+noun[1]+num[2])

    print(adj[x]+noun[2]+num[0])
    print(adj[x]+noun[2]+num[1])
    print(adj[x]+noun[2]+num[2])
```

I know this only prints but same concept no?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the script more compact, I suggest to look at [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

adj = ["united", "dramatic", "green"]
noun = ["ladder", "axe", "tiger"]
num = [str(i) for i in range(3)] # <-- you can increase the number

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    for c in product(adj, noun, num):
        print(''.join(c), file=f_out)
```

This creates `file.txt` with content:

```
unitedladder0
unitedladder1
unitedladder2
unitedaxe0
unitedaxe1
unitedaxe2
unitedtiger0
unitedtiger1
unitedtiger2
dramaticladder0
dramaticladder1
dramaticladder2
dramaticaxe0
dramaticaxe1
dramaticaxe2
dramatictiger0
dramatictiger1
dramatictiger2
greenladder0
greenladder1
greenladder2
greenaxe0
greenaxe1
greenaxe2
greentiger0
greentiger1
greentiger2
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you both! Now to grind putting in values and more lists.

Comment: Just as an FYI I've noticed that sometimes default network passwords are commonly and adjective+noun+(three digit number)

Comment: Any way i can make the digits fill with zeros so that i get "000"-"099"??? im thinking maybe ill make it its own list and begin num at 100

Comment: @C0D3X You can do `num = ['{:>03d}'.format(i) for i in range(3)]` That way you get 3 digits, zero padded from the left.

Comment: @ Adrej Kesely 

SUPER awesome! This is going to be easy to make into a CLI tool.

and if im understanding correctly the  '{:>03d}'.format means it formats for 3 decimal places??

Comment: @C0D3X I recommend this tutorial - I learned it from there https://pyformat.info/#string_pad_align

Comment: @AndrejKeseley any thoughts on the above?

Comment: @C0D3X I recommend to open a new question here on StackOverflow and not rewrite old one (it creates confusion). So revert this question to old version and open a new one and I'll answer it if I can.

Comment: Another day. i just did that earlier and was told that it was too similar in context to this one and that "questions should be contained within themselves" and it even got 3 downvotes within 15min XD

Answer (score 1):

Using `itertools.product`:

```
adj = ["united", "dramatic", "green"]
noun = ["ladder", "axe", "tiger"]
num = ["0", "1", "2"]

print(list(itertools.product(adj, noun, num)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a very simple code. Please run my code and let me know your opinion.

```
import itertools

filename = "mywordlist.txt"


adj = ["united", "dramatic", "green"]
noun = ["ladder", "axe", "tiger"]
num = [str(i) for i in range(4)] # from '0' to '3'

total_list = [adj, noun, num]

with open(filename, "w") as fp:
    for i in itertools.product(*total_list):
        combined_word = " ".join(i)
        print(combined_word)
        fp.write(combined_word)
        fp.write('\n')
```

If you want to add a combination of only adj and noun, you can use the following code;

```
import itertools

filename = "mywordlist.txt"

adj = ["united", "dramatic", "green"]
noun = ["ladder", "axe", "tiger"]
num = [str(i) for i in range(4)] # from '0' to '3'
num.insert(0, "")

total_list = [adj, noun, num]

with open(filename, "w") as fp:
    for i in itertools.product(*total_list):
        combined_word = " ".join(i)
        print(combined_word)
        fp.write(combined_word)
        fp.write('\n')
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: almost! I needed the concatenation of the values

Comment: It seems that what your doing here may be able to help me accomplish the above *edited* script.